# Protecting a ringworld from solar radiation

Tags: science-based, engineering, space-constructs, radiation

How can I protect a ringworld (which creates 1g artificial gravity and has an earth-like atmosphere) from the things that earth's magnetic field protects us? (using real-world physics)

Answer (score 7):

If you read *[Ringworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringworld)* or *[Bigger Than Worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigger_Than_Worlds)* you'll see that the ringworld, as a giant spinning super conductor, has a magnetic field, a much more powerful one than Earth's, powerful enough to turn its star into a particle beam weapon when needed. This spinning conductor model is substantially similar in operation to Earth's [geodynamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo_theory).